# Firestore Sharing data with other users

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a travel app in flutter for people to create trips and share with other users that can modify its contents. I'm currently using firebase authentication so each user has an unique id. I'm having trouble understanding what concept I should use to share **trip1** with **user2**. I found out [documentReferences](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) allow you to share the specific path of the trip with other users but it doesn't necessarily add the trip to **user2** so they can see it on their dashboard. Is documentReferences the correct way to share data with other users?

[image: Data structure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create another collection with the name trips or something you want. It is better to separate the user's data and the trip's data since you are going to share it from one user to another. You can create a unique document for trip 1 and add the location's name as trip 1's value. This way you can filter out where each specific trip is by using `.where()`. Inside trip1 you can store the reviews of each user inside it. Watch these two videos so that you will be able to understand how to implement it: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haMOUb3KVSo. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks! I will look into those videos. If I separate the trips data, can I restrict the view to trip1 so user3 can't see the data?

Comment: yes. You add a value that allows only certain users to view the data. For that, you will want to look in to firestore rules. You can set a rule to check if the incoming authenticated id matches the list of allowed authenticated ids inside the database.

Comment: Thanks again! I have been trying to understand this for a week and you got me the answer in no time.

Comment: @EdgarJ. Good Luck in your project!